# Page reload by javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a page which contains multiple tabs. I want to reload the page but it should stay on the same page.
I tried reloading by using
window.location.reload() 
But its redirecting to the 1st page which i dont want.
Please suggest me other ways of reloading by using js.

Comment: you mean stay on same `tab`?

Comment: Have u tried localstorage or cookies ?

Comment: Just store your tab id somewhere (localstorage, dbstorage, url) and try restore it on each page initialization.

Comment: Actually, my requirement is whenever the user clicks on some different tab, it should reload all other tabs and stay on the clicked tab.

Comment: Than I don't understand. What for you need to reload all other tabs? Are they visible? Are they need data needs to be reloaded?

Comment: In all tabs we have some fields textfield, dropdown etc. The user has entered some value for those fields. So i want whenever the user nevigates to other tab it should reset the fields.

Comment: You could call the `reset()` method on the forms in all the other tabs to set all the input fields back to their default values.

Comment: What does `node.js` have to do with this? This is running in the browser, not the server.

Answer (score 0):

if you can use query parameters in url, then it will work without localstorage, sessionstorage, cache or cookies.

Eg: www.something.com?reloaded=true&tab_num=2

Answer (score 0):

> In all tabs we have some fields textfield, dropdown etc. The user has entered some value for those fields. So i want whenever the user nevigates to other tab it should reset the fields.

I would try to go this way.

Most of all, on each tab you have initialization method that set some initial values into your controls. So, you need to: 
1. Subscribe on event when tab is changed. Realization of this depends on your plugin. 
2. On tab change - re initialize tab and set your values empty again.

This approach will 
1. Update only one tab instead of all (this will be faster)
2. Give you control under initialization of each tab. 
3. Make a point where you can easily add some additional logic when new requirements come.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

See attached code snippet. To do a reload you can call it through javascript. I attached the javascript function to a HTML button to demonstrate the function.

This solution should work, since you have already pressed the tab.
If you do not want it triggered by the HTML button you can anyhow use the function and let it run from javascript.

```js
function pageReload() {
location.reload();
}
```

```css
#button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </head>
  <body>

  <button id="button" type="button" name="button" onclick="pageReload()">Reload</button>

<script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: TS wants not only reload a page but restore users tab

Comment: If TS uses the javascript function and map it to be executed after tab click, then the effect will be a reload of that specific page.